# Webpack watch mode + Express Static causes Chrome to hang?

Tags: javascript, express, webpack

I recently added Typescript to my codebase, which made Webpack take longer to compile. I'm running Webpack in watch mode. I noticed that if I refreshed Chrome while Webpack was recompiling, the JS file gets stuck on "pending":

[image]

I need to close and re-open the tab to get past this. I'm using Express's `static` to serve the files.

Has anyone had this issue before? How can I configure Webpack or Express to solve this?

Comment: Could you provide your webpack config?

Comment: It's pretty complicated, 200+ lines spread across 3 files. I looked at every config and there's nothing unusual, is there a particular config that's likely the issue?

Comment: The plugins sections would provide information how files gets included. You could add these debugging parameters `webpack --progress --profile --debug --display-error-details` to have some details about the compiling process.